# Angular 9 routing anonymous parameters

Tags: angular, routes

I'm working in Angular 9, and trying to capture a route with unknown number of parameters in the URL to express a nested folder structure.

An example group would look like this: /group/:groupId/child1/childofchild1/childofchildofchild1

I don't know how many parameters would follow the :groupId parameter.

Right now, I have a route like this in app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'group/:groupId', component: GroupComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix' },
]);
```

This will match a URL like /group/1, but will not match /group/1/a, and throws an error saying, "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'group/1/a'" despite being a prefix pathMatch.

I's really like to set up a route like this:

```
{ path: 'group/:groupId/:path }
```

and have the route 'group/1/a/b/c' resolve the :path parameter to 'a/b/c'.

Comment: I would recommend using queryParams instead of path variables.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use wildcards, specifically **:

```
path: 'group/:groupId/**', component: GroupComponent,  //...
```

Comment: I just tried that again to make sure. It doesn't work.